# NSwagStudio: Generate C# Controller with [Authorize]

Tags: c#, openapi, nswagstudio

I'd like to have the automatically generate output of NSwagStudio to contain an `[Authorize]` attribute.

I try to program an API with NSwagStudio and to secure it with `[Authorize]`, such that my automatically generated controller code from NSwagStudio looks like this:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Returns a list of Things.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>A JSON array of Things</returns>
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.HttpGet, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("Thing", Name = "Thing"), Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<Thing>> Machine()
{
    return _implementation.ThingAsync();
}
```

I added the

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
```

attribute manually, which works fine, but what do I have to put in the OpenAPI specification, to write the attribute to a specific API path automatically?

```yaml
 /Thing:
    get:
      summary: Returns a list of Things.
      responses:
        "200": # status code
          description: A JSON array of Things
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: "#/components/schemas/Thing"
```

Comment: Where in your OpenApi file would you specify the Authorization rules? `[Authorize(Roles = "User")]` is an implementation detail - your app decides that it's going to be a role and the name of said role. The client doesn't care.

Comment: True. As you can see I new to this. Would you have a better suggestion? I just don't want the attributes to be overwritten every time a regenearte the controller.

Comment: OpenAPI Specification has the concept of [security schemes](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/), which seems to be what you need. Roles can be represented as OAuth 2.0 scopes; in OAS 3.1 the roles can also be defined for API keys and other security scheme. But I'm not sure if NSwagStudio translates the security schemes to `[Authorize]` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that at this point in time (currently using v13.18.2 of NSwag) that it supports this. If you're only looking to decorate the controller, then you can take advantage of the fact that the controller classes are written as partial classes, so you can add your own partial class with the appropriate tag.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "User")]
public partial class ControllerGeneratedByNSwag
{
}
```

(don't forget the file needs to be in the same namespace and same assembly as the generated class). It's manual, but at least when you rebuild the generated classes, your customisation won't get deleted.

If you're wanting to decorate individual classes with attributes set from the OpenAPI spec, then you're in the same boat I am in! I believe the solution is to create a customised Liquid template (for `Controller.Methods.Annotations.liquid`). You can follow my progress as such in the [GitHub issue #2478](https://github.com/RicoSuter/NSwag/issues/2478).